# How to make Android Studio automatically suggest code fixes

Tags: android, android-studio

When using Android Studio, I want to be able to just put the mouse cursor on top of a code word with a compiler error and get a drop down list with fix suggestions. Right now in order to open that list, I must press ALT + ENTER. How can I make Android Studio to open the list automatically when the coursor is above the error line?

Comment: Check out [POWER SAVE MODE didn't disable on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791396/power-save-mode-didnt-disable-on-android-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there was an update to the Android Studio and this feature was added. You need to play with the error line a bit (sometimes there's a need to press it a few times) and then you'll get the option to view code fixes.

Answer (score 1):

In your Android Studio go to:
Settings > Editor > Code Completion and check in 'Autopopup code completion'

You might check as well the other options in the tab - e.g. delay in ms.

Comment: The code completion option is already checked and the code completion itself is working. I want to get an autopopup error fix suggestion, not code completion.

Comment: Unfortunately, is might not be possible with the current version of Android Studio. It will show the popup with additional info on mouse hover, but not clickable solutions to pick from.