# POWER SAVE MODE didn't disable on Android Studio

Tags: android

I tried to disable Power Save Mode on Android Studio 1.2.1.1 several times in order to activate Code Complete feature but didn't disable.

I'm running the studio on Windows 7.

What could be the problem? someone please help

Comment: Related post - [What is “Power Save Mode” in IntelliJ IDEA and other Jetbrains IDEs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11725605/465053)

Answer (score 6):

You can try this :

You can also check if Power Save Mode on File menu is disabled.

```
                                 'OR'
```

Go File > Invalidate Caches / Restart... > Click at Invalidate and Restart

This really works for me...[Can't Anlyze code because of Power save mode](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61844#c4)

Comment: Thanks, Go File > Invalidate Caches / Restart... > works for me

Answer (score 5):

Uncheck "Power save mode" as shown below:

[image]

Comment: I couldn't find the settings for it in the New UI of Android Studio UI, thanks! 